# WCF -An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

I try to get list from service like this:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      MyClient proxy = new MyClient();
      List<X> l = proxy.Func(1).ToList();
    }
```

X is class from DLL of entity framework project.

My function in service look like this:

```
    public List<X> Func(int NUM)
    {                      
        ProjectContext MyContext = new ProjectContext();
        s = MyContext.X.ToList();
        return s;

    }
```

My context define like this:

```
public class ProjectContext : DbContext
{

    public ProjectContext ()
        : base("name=ApplicationServices")
    {
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled=false;
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    public DbSet<XX> X{ get; set; }

}
```

I get error:

An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to XXX. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

Comment: Please enable WCF logging to have more info : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx

Comment: As Fabske says please enable the loglistener and get the 'real' exception from there.

Comment: I did not understand how I should use it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception could be due to cyclic reference. Mark the navigational properties in your entities with `IgnoreDataMember` attribute so they don't take part in serialization.

Comment: What is navigational properties? The context?

Comment: Let say you have Employee and Department classes. The Employee class contains a property of type Department and Department contains a property of collection of Employees. If you take the Employee class the Department property is a navigational property. Since both the classes reference each other if you try to serialize an Employee instance you will get into some trouble.

Comment: So I'm supposed to put the IgnoreDataMember attribute on the employ object that i have in Department in ef project?

Comment: You can decorate on both but I'll do mainly in the collection

Answer (score 1):

I'm used to be like you and got the same error.
And I had resolve that by create a Data Contract to declare class X like this.

```
[DataContract]
public class StudentX
{       [DataMember]
        public string studentId;
        [DataMember]
        public string studentName;
        [DataMember]
        public string studentBirthday;


        public Studentx(string Id, string Name, string Birthday)
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization
            studentId= Id;
            studentName = Name;
            studentBirthday= Birthday;               
        }
 }
```

I think the reason u got that error because the client didn't understand the Object X, so does the List.

Regards

Comment: I think that my problem is in object ProjectContext because when i send list of X class that don't come from  ProjectContext it's OK

Comment: @BuiAkinori While it is possible to serialize fields this way, it is better to make them properties `public string StudentID { get; set; }`

Comment: In the question you can see that i disable the Lazy loading